# Cannot bind to event via reflection on VS2015

Tags: vb.net, roslyn, dataadapter, devart

I've a piece of code that fills a database table from a `DataTable` using a `DbDataAdapter`.

The `DbDataAdapter` is created via `DbProviderFactory.CreateDataAdapter` method, where `DbProviderFactory` is provided by [Devart dotConnect](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/).
We use Devart's drivers for Oracle, SqlServer and Postgres.

Since I have nearly 100k rows in my `DataTable`, I need to bind to the `RowUpdated` event (to update a progress bar) which unfortunately is not defined on a common interface, despite it is available in all the mentioned database drivers.

Therefore I bind it via reflection with this code:

```
Dim eventInfo As System.Reflection.EventInfo = adapter.GetType().GetEvent("RowUpdated")
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(adapter, [Delegate].CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType,
                          (Sub(s As Object, e As EventArgs) UpdateProgress(s, e)).Method))
```

This perfectly works if compiled with VS2013, but fails ***at runtime*** if compiled on Roslyn (VS2015), with this exception:

> Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type

Any help on this?

Neither using `Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlRowUpdatedEventHandler` (I'm currently on Postgres) as the type of `e` works.

Comment: Does it work with `e As Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlRowUpdatedEventArgs` in the handler?

Comment: @djv ouch! I used the event handler, instead of event args! I'll try tomorrow!

Comment: @djv I'll try the correct one tomorrow, anyway I'd like to avoid to be so specific because this way I would have to test for the DbType and then use the specific event.

Comment: Right, if the same handler must work for Oracle, SqlServer and Postgres. It would be interesting to see if that works, then it might be a question for Devart support.

Comment: @djv I'd want to understand what changed on Roslyn that make it doesn't work...

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use Reflection? What about `AddHandler adapter.RowUpdated, Sub(s As Object, e As EventArgs) UpdateProgress(s, e)`?

Comment: As I wrote in the question, `adapter` has no `RowUpdated` event because it is not of a specific class, the event is defined on each specific adapter (i.e. OracleDataAdapter, PgSqlDataAdapter etc). I can for sure test for the correct DB type at runtime and then perform a `select case` to cast `adapter` to che correct specific type, but I'd like to avoid this "so specific" approach.

Comment: @djv Neither using `PgSqlRowUpdatedEventArgs` works. But if I cast the adapter to the specific type, it works with a simple `AddHandler` statement, even if the type of `e` is not specific.

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777483/system-data-common-dataadapter-rowupdated-rowupdating-events-not-present. If that doesn't help, I still think Devart support is your best bet. Seems pretty standard to want to generically handle all table updates. Good luck!

Comment: @djv Thanks, I'll give it a try. The answer is from 2013 so it could not work as well in Roslyn, but it's worth to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777483/system-data-common-dataadapter-rowupdated-rowupdating-events-not-present) posted in a comment by @djv, I finally get to the culprit.

It seems that, with Roslyn (VS2015), you need to explicitly declare the `Delegate` prior to binding the event handler.

For example, in my case, I need to write:

```
Public Delegate Sub RowUpdatedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As RowUpdatedEventArgs)
```

And then:

```
Dim eventInfo As System.Reflection.EventInfo = adpt.GetType().GetEvent("RowUpdated")
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(adpt, [Delegate].CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType,
                          DirectCast(AddressOf UpdateProgress, RowUpdatedEventHandler).Method))
```

---

Also it seems it has some issues with lamdas. For example, this DOES NOT WORK:

```
Dim eventInfo As System.Reflection.EventInfo = adpt.GetType().GetEvent("RowUpdated")
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(adpt, [Delegate].CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType,
                          DirectCast((Sub(s As Object, e As RowUpdatedEventArgs) UpdateProgress(s, e)), RowUpdatedEventHandler).Method))
```

*(with or without `DirectCast` on the lambda expression)*